# angular pass interpolation as function parameter

Tags: angular, templates, concatenation, interpolation

I have a function to display a tooltip. This function accepts string param. I want to pass the translated string to this function. But when I pass the value is not parsed and displayed as text.

```
'<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="{{'placeholder_val'|translate}}" ngModel name="name"
      [ngbPopover]="tipContent" popoverClass="help-tips" [autoClose]="'outside'" triggers="manual"
           #p1="ngbPopover"
           (click)="toggleTips(p1, '{{`tootltip_val`|translate}}')">'
```

Comment: Please, perform the translation in the function itself, not in the template. I could elaborate more if you need further clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean:

```
(click)="toggleTips(p1, {{'tootltip_val' | translate}})"
```

instead of

```
(click)="toggleTips(p1, '{{`tootltip_val`|translate}}')">
```

```
<input
  type="text"
  class="form-control"
  placeholder="{{'placeholder_val' | translate}}"
  ngModel
  name="name"
  [ngbPopover]="tipContent"
  popoverClass="help-tips"
  [autoClose]="'outside'"
  triggers="manual"
  #p1="ngbPopover"
  (click)="toggleTips(p1, {{'tootltip_val' | translate}})" />
```

Note also that your variable is named `tootltip_val` instead of `tooltip_val`, maybe that is also the source of error?

Lastly:

- If `tootltip_val` is a **static string** that is mapped to your translation system, then `{{'tootltip_val' | translate}}` is fine.
- If `tootltip_val` is a **dynamic variable** set in your `.ts` file, you should instead be using `{{tootltip_val | translate}}`